# What type of sensor do you think is best for use in liquids?

Tags: sensors

I am looking for a level controller that's going to be used in an industrial setting. My main concerns are high level of precision and low total error band. Do you have any recommendations? Both types and brands/specific products would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of sensor solutions have reviewed? Generally in the forum we try not make recommendations instead provide feedback on your solutions.

Comment: It might help those who could assist you if mentioned the scale of the volume of liquid to be measured. Are you looking at vat with capacity of the 1000s of liters or something very small, but critical?

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here .. please remove the part that asks about brands/specific products

Comment: Does it need to be « in » the liquid? What about remote sensors?

Comment: You need to better describe the liquid (e.g. temperature, pressure, pH, solids content) and the process that is being controlled. Does your company have specifications for this type of instrumentation? https://new.abb.com/products/measurement-products/level/a-dozen-ways-to-measure-fluid-level

Comment: @J.Ari great link.   It helps if you give us a hint what you want to do with the measurement. My toilet has a level controller that does its job to spec and is low cost but a float is listed on the ABB web site.  I dimly recall a sensor from years ago that measured the level by how much heat was conduced from a uniform heater.  There are as many ways to measure a level as there are types of levels to measure.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure detectors are the gold standard.  Ultrasonic is available if it's needed.  There are various other niche instruments available.